# Error creating jpa repositories after heroku app deployment

Tags: java, heroku, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

Unable to run the app after deployment. Added clearDB addons and modified the db url,username and password accordingly.

Connected to heroku cleardb from sql workbench and created tables successfully but still I get the errors:

```
ion.java:263) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448915+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c6e82b.C
GLIB$config$0(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448915+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c6e82b$$
FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$78b891a4.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2
.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448948+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cglib.pro
xy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448950+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.a
nnotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(Configurati
onClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448950+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c6e82b.c
onfig(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448951+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448952+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448953+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodA
ccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]

2016-11-27T15:31:13.448953+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invo
ke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448954+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448954+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 142 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448956+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.bean
s.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.re
pository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; n
ested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Erro
r creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bea
n)#17f1b4d4' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] wh
ile setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner be
an)#17f1b4d4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while set
ting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory
.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' def
ined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/Hibe
rnateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested excep
tion is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested s
ervice [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448957+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448957+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolv
er.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448958+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 163 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448959+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.bean
s.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository':
 Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#17f1b4d4' of type [org.springframework.o
rm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Err
or creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17f1b4d4': Cannot resolve reference to
bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
 with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springfram
ework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocatio
n of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceEx
ception: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.J
dbcEnvironment]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448960+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueRes
olver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448960+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionV
alueResolver.java:129) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448984+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAuto
wireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEA
SE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448985+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:1231) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448986+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448986+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448987+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spr
ing-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448988+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448989+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[sprin
g-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448997+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-
beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448998+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.s
upport.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087)
~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448998+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.repo
sitory.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:95) ~[sprin
g-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448998+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.repo
sitory.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.ja
va:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448999+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.repo
sitory.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-1
.12.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.448999+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositories(RepositoryRestMvcConf
iguration.java:194) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449000+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c6e82b.C
GLIB$repositories$13(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:
na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449000+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c6e82b$$
FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$78b891a4.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2
.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449001+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cglib.pro
xy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449001+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.a
nnotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(Configurati
onClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449001+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.data.rest
.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2c6e82b.r
epositories(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449002+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449002+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449003+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodA
ccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]

2016-11-27T15:31:13.449003+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invo
ke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102-cedar14]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449004+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449004+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 164 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449037+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.bean
s.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17f
1b4d4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting co
nstructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCr
eationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
 class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJp
aAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449038+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueRes
olver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449039+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionV
alueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449040+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver
.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449040+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolv
er.java:448) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449044+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(Ab
stractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4
.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449045+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutow
ireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEAS
E]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449046+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449046+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449046+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueRes
olver.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449047+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 188 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449047+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.bean
s.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFac
tory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm
/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nes
ted exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create re
quested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449048+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449048+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449048+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spr
ing-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[sprin
g-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449050+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-
beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449052+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueRes
olver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449052+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 196 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449053+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.service.sp
i.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdb
c.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449053+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.interna
l.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264
) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449054+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.interna
l.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java
:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449054+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.interna
l.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~
[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449055+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.interna
l.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java
:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449054+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.int
ernal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.
11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449055+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.interna
l.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~
[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449055+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.i
nternal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl
.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.model.proc
ess.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hib
ernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449057+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.v
endor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:
4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449058+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.L
ocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalCont
ainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.R
ELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449058+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.A
bstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityMa
nagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449057+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.intern
al.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:87
4) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449059+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.A
bstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryB
ean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.model.proc
ess.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[
hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449059+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE
]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449059+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.intern
al.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java
:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449060+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 203 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449060+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateE
xception: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect
' not set
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449061+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dia
lect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~
[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449061+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dia
lect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibe
rnate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449061+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env
.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java
:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449087+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env
.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java
:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449088+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.i
nternal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.
java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449089+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.interna
l.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254
) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449090+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 219 common frames omitted
2016-11-27T15:31:13.449090+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-11-27T15:31:13.632183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-11-27T15:31:13.605808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-11-27T15:34:03.069091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rootscopeit-in-spring.herokuapp.com request_id=77
89d9e8-0b76-4e35-adc4-a98d61be5242 fwd="183.83.237.247" dyno= connect= service=
status=503 bytes=
```

Db details:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_505130b7010a272?reconnect=true
jdbc.username=b35ede5944880e
jdbc.password=password here
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8084
```

App config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${init-db:false}")
    private String initDatabase;

    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data.sql"));
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
        dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(initDatabase));
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
}
```

I am using spring version 1.4.3 in heroku. I am not sure this is right version supported by heroku. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

First, reset your database credentials immediately (because you've posted them publicly on the internet). You'll have to refer to the [ClearDB documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb) for instructions.

Then [use the `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url) instead of hardcoding your connection parameters. You can put this in your code:

```
dataSource.setUrl(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
```

If this still gives you problems, try the [JawsDB add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb) instead (it seems to have less problems).

Comment: I didn't mention the password in question

Comment: The problem is that your JDBC URL is not a JDBC URL. it should start with `jdbc:mysql://` but you have just `mysql://`

Comment: I will try with jdbc-url as you have mentioned. I already tried jdbc:

Comment: so I need to change this line as well? `JDBC_DATABASE_URL=mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_505130b7010a272?reconnect=true` ???

Comment: where do you have that line? `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` is set for you. Regardless, any JDBC url should begin with `jdbc:`

Comment: It's ok I fixed it. JDBC_URL is not required